# JSON to Java POJO not working for simple structure?

Tags: java, json, jackson

JSON:

```
{
  "246": {
    "test1": "one" 
  },
  "355": {
    "test2": "two"
  }
}
```

Java POJO

```
class POJO{
  private HashMap<String, SubPojo> subMap;

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void addToMap(String key, SubPojo val){ subMap.put(key, value); }
}

class SubPojo{
  private HashMap<String, String> map; 
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void addToMap(String key, String val) { map.put(key, value);}
}
```

In my code I do: (using **Jackson**)

```
POJO testing = (new ObjectMapper()).convertValue("path/to/json", POJO.class);
```

I get an exception saying:

```
"Unrecognized field `246`..."
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `POJO` has a field `subMap` but not `246`. Thus you need to tell the object mapper that every unknown field should be handled as a key into `subMap` instead of an actual property. How that's done depends on the json library you're using. Btw, you need to do the same for `SubPojo`.

Comment: @Thomas, I am using JackSon, can you guide me here?

Comment: Basically you need to use the annotation `@JsonAnySetter` (and  `@JsonAnyGetter` if you want to serialize to json as well).

Comment: Alternatively, don't define any classes and parse into a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, though you will have to use `TypeReference` to prevent loss of generic type arguments.

Comment: Note that if all your objects basically are maps you could also just parse that json into maps or into the generic tree format via `ObjectMapper.readTree(json)`.

Comment: @Thomas, I tried that and seem to get the same error, I've updated the question. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Basically your code should work when the val/value issue is fixed and 2 adjustments are made: 1) initialize the maps otherwise you'll get NPEs and 2) instead of `convertValue(...)` try `readValue( ...)`. If this doesn't work we'd need to know which version of Jackson you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class Pojo {
    private Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addToMap(String key, Object value) {
        this.map.put(key, value);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String,Object> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

There is an [article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) which covers various Jackson annotations, including this one, and some basics on the [Jackson wiki](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations).

Comment: What I have a nested Value object though as in my example?

Answer (score 0):

`converValue` method is used to convert objects. See `JavaDoc`:

> Convenience method for doing two-step conversion from given value,
>   into instance of given value type, if (but only if!) conversion is
>   needed. If given value is already of requested type, value is returned
>   as is. This method is functionally similar to first serializing given
>   value into JSON, and then binding JSON data into value of given type,
>   but should be more efficient since full serialization does not (need
>   to) occur. However, same converters (serializers, deserializers) will
>   be used as for data binding, meaning same object mapper configuration
>   works.

For example, you can "convert" `File` to `String` like this:

```
mapper.convertValue(jsonFile, String.class)
```

Where `jsonFile` is an instance of `File` class. Example result could be: `path/to/json`.

To deserialise `JSON` payload use one from `readValue` method family.

You can create your `POJO` with constructor annotated `JsonCreator`:

```
class Pojo {

    private final Map<String, SubPojo> map;

    @JsonCreator
    public Pojo(Map<String, SubPojo> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public Map<String, SubPojo> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pojo{" +
                "map=" + map +
                '}';
    }
}

class SubPojo {

    private Map<String, String> map;

    @JsonCreator
    public SubPojo(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SubPojo{" +
                "map=" + map +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And simple usage. To read `JSON` from file use `readValue` method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Pojo map = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Pojo.class);
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Pojo{map={246=SubPojo{map={test1=one}}, 355=SubPojo{map={test2=two}}}}
```

If you would like to stay with your data model use `JsonAnySetter` annotation. Your data model could look like this:

```
class Pojo {
    private Map<String, SubPojo> subMap = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addToMap(String key, SubPojo value) {
        subMap.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "POJO{" +
                "subMap=" + subMap +
                '}';
    }
}

class SubPojo {
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addToMap(String key, String value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SubPojo{" +
                "map=" + map +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above usage example prints:

```
POJO{subMap={355=SubPojo{map={test2=two}}, 246=SubPojo{map={test1=one}}}}
```

Comment: How does this work with nested even further though as in my example?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create any POJO classes to parse that JSON text, since it can be parsed into a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`.

You will have to use a `TypeReference` to prevent loss of the generic type arguments.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new ObjectMapper()
        .readValue(new File("test.json"),
                   new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {});
```

Printing that `data` map, using the JSON text in the question, will show:

```
{246={test1=one}, 355={test2=two}}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but a requirement is for me to wrap it.